# workbox: Set debug mode dynamically

Tags: service-worker, workbox

**Library Affected**:
workbox.setConfig

**Browser & Platform**:
"all browsers".*

**Issue or Feature Request Description**:
I am planning to set debug mode : true 
here is the process i am following :

1. using PWA to store the mode value : true/false in a cache
2. Opening the cache and set the debug value using the stored variable.
3. the problem is everything is async and install event is getting called before workbox.setconfig

Does anyone know any workaround for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The various `workbox.*` methods need to be executed synchronously at service worker startup, in order to load the required runtime bundles and establish the proper event listeners before events start firing. You're not going to be able to do anything asynchronous, like read from the Cache Storage API or IndexedDB, prior to initializing Workbox.

I don't know how much flexibility you need in terms of toggling whether Workbox is in debug mode or not, but maybe the following would help. It allows you to use a URL query parameter to determine whether a given service worker registration will [trigger Workbox's debug mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/troubleshoot-and-debug#debugging_workbox) or not.

```
// Inside your service worker,
// before you make any other calls to workbox.* methods.

const url = new URL(location.href);
const debug = url.searchParams.has('debug');
workbox.setConfig({debug});
```

and then when you register:

```
// To enable debugging:
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js?debug');
// To run without debugging:
// navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
```

You might already know this, but Workbox will automatically switch into `debug: true` mode when it detects it's running on `localhost`, and run in production mode by default otherwise.

Comment: just have a look at my code at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1525  . We are trying to update it via cache in chrome but this code is not working in edge. Any pointers why is it happening ? . In edge it is not able to find modules like workbox-core etc